# How to handle a SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE from SCHANNEL received during TLS 1.3 Negotiation

Tags: winapi, windows-11, tls1.3

I have a client application that uses **SCHANNEL** to negotiate **TLS 1.1** and **TLS 1.2** which has worked for years.

I recently changed the code to use **SCH_CREDENTIALS** instead of **SCHANNEL_CRED** and it still works for **TLS 1.2** (and I presume TLS 1.1) on Windows 10. When run on Windows 11, it attempts **TLS 1.3** as expected and desired. However, it fails when **SCHANNEL** returns a **SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE** status. This status confuses me because my understanding is that renegotiations was removed from 1.3 due to security concerns. (I never had to implement it in for 1.1 or 1.2.)

In the [Microsoft Security blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/blog/2020/08/20/taking-transport-layer-security-tls-to-the-next-level-with-tls-1-3/), which talks about upgrading to **TLS 1.3**, the author says to make the upgraded code correctly handles the **SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE** status but gives no hint as what it should do.

Please provide some information about what to do with the **SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE** status.

Note that this is not a web client. This is an encrypted connection for a custom protocol and is directly calling **SCHANNEL**.  I can reproduce the problem when attempting to connect to an OpenSSL based server.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Negotiating an Schannel Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/renegotiating-an-schannel-connection):

> When you receive the SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE return code, your application must call AcceptSecurityContext (Schannel)    (servers) or InitializeSecurityContext (Schannel)    (clients), passing in empty input buffers. After this call returns a value, proceed as though your application were creating a new connection

Comment: Yes, I have read that statement.  However, the RFC for TLS 1.3 says there is not renegotiation in the protocol.  Can you confirm that you have SChannel doing a renegotiation while using TLS 1.3?

Comment: Sorry, it's been years since I actually used SSPI myself. The only thing I can confirm here is that is what the docs say to do in case of SEC_I_RENEGOTIATE.

Comment: Yes, that was for SSL and TLS before 1.3, even though I never implemented that either as none of the servers I had to hit asked for renegotiation.